# Time.Timescale is not pausing the game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

This is the script of a ball game that I am building.
The game is supposed to pause once it hits `Time.timescale` but it doesn't.

I need to know what I did wrong and what I need to change here.

I am a beginner in Unity and C# so i might have messed up everything.

If there is any other way to pause the game rather than using `Time.timescale` i would like to know it also.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class PauseScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool paused = false;
    void Start()
    {
        paused = false;
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Pause()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("p") && paused == false)
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            paused = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("p") && paused == true)
        {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            paused = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Ball.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{  
    
    //configuration parameter
    [SerializeField] Paddle paddleInitial;
    [SerializeField] float horizontalPush = 2f;
    [SerializeField] float verticalPush = 15f;
    [SerializeField] AudioClip[] ballSounds; 

    //state parameter
    Vector2 paddleToBallVector;
    bool mouseButtonClicked = false;

    //Cached COmponent References
    AudioSource myAudioSource;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        paddleToBallVector = transform.position - paddleInitial.transform.position;
        myAudioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (mouseButtonClicked == false)
        {
            stickBallToPaddle();
            launchOnMouseClick();
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(horizontalPush,verticalPush);
        }
    }

    private void launchOnMouseClick()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            mouseButtonClicked = true;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(horizontalPush, verticalPush);
        }
    }

    private void stickBallToPaddle()
    {
        Vector2 paddlePosition = new Vector2(paddleInitial.transform.position.x, paddleInitial.transform.position.y);
        transform.position = paddlePosition + paddleToBallVector;
    }

    //audio settings
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (mouseButtonClicked)
        {
            AudioClip clip = ballSounds[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, ballSounds.Length)];
           myAudioSource.PlayOneShot(clip);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At no point in that code do you change the timescale so... how can we tell you why its not working without the code thats giving you trouble?

Comment: Question needs to include a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of potential issues.

1. Your function should be called `Update`, or it won't run once per frame
2. `Input.GetKeyDown` returns if a key has started being pressed, but this persists on the current frame (it's only reset before the next `Update` call, so it will return true every time you call it in the same `Update` function block)

When you hit P, you check if the key is down then set the pause flag/timescale, but then you do another if check in the update method that does the opposite.

```
    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Pause()
    {
        // The p key is down and the game isn't paused, set timescale to 0 and paused to true...
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("p") && paused == false)
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            paused = true;
        }

        // The p key is still down since we are on the same frame and paused flag is set so here we set timescale to 1 and paused to false...
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("p") && paused == true)
        {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            paused = false;
        }
    }
```

You probably want to make sure only one of these conditions runs per update and ensure the function is called `Update` or it won't run once per frame

```
    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("p") && paused == false)
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            paused = true;
        }
        // Use else to make sure this block only gets executed if the above doesn't
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown("p") && paused == true)
        {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            paused = false;
        }
    }
```

There are many ways to skin a cat so to speak; alternative code could look something like this:

```
public void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("p"))
    {
        // Toggle paused
        paused != paused;
        // Use ternary operator to save lines because making code harder to read is fun
        Time.timeScale = paused ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

-- Edit:

Also make sure you are multiplying any vectors for movement etc by `deltaTime` each frame - otherwise your simulation will continue.

You may also need to explicitly handle paused for other aspects such as animations etc - it depends on how they are implemented, but as long as they consider the delta frame by frame they will react when `timeScale` is set to 0 as expected.

Comment: I did as you suggested but didn't work. The script is working fine but the game won't pause. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Oeqlbt6HYd8QGRxO0B4CJqeM_gefH02u/view?usp=sharing). @Charleh

Comment: Have you considered that you might not be using a method of moving your objects that uses delta time and therefore timescale won't affect your simulation?

Comment: You need to ensure you are multiplying vectors (such as velocities) by delta time during your physics simulation, you also need to explicitly check if the game is paused in some places in order to prevent certain game functions from running (for example you don't want to allow the user to score points or move if the game is paused, it sounds like you are making a breakout style game and the paddle moves with the mouse)

Comment: yaa i guess that's the problem because i didn't define the movement by using delta time instead i used some fixed values.@Charleh